# In with node.js riak-js .getClient returns empty object

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, riak

I am trying to do this with node.js and riak-js

```
db = require('./riak-js/lib').getClient({host: "localhost", port: "8098" });
console.log db
```

*Note, this is Coffee-Script code.*

The db variable always ends up as { }

I have cloned the latest version of riak-js from github. I have also tried the npm distributed version, but always the same result.

I have a single node of riak running on my local machine. I can access it with any browser with url localhost:8098

Does anyone have any suggestion why this is failing for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* just an empty object, the magic is in it's prototype :)

try this:

```
db = require('riak-js').getClient({ debug:true })

db.save 'tests', 1, { works: 'fine' }, (err) ->
  db.getAll 'tests'
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. However I still don't understand why I get no results from my saves and getAll. Will look further into this.

Comment: Ok, the db object works. However it doesn't seem to me as if data is actually stored in the Riak database. It take ages to store one document and I never get any results when asking to fetch them.

Comment: what does your code look like? run `riak-admin test` and see if it's all right.

Comment: you are right it doesn't work properly, it timed out. The http-interface did work however.